# Table Architecture Difficulty with Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, architecture

I'm working on a practice problem with DDL as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  last_name VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
;

CREATE TABLE cd (
  id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  artist VARCHAR(50),
  title VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  owner SMALLINT,
  FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES people(id)
  )
;

CREATE TABLE lend (
  id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cd_id SMALLINT,
  lend_to SMALLINT,
  FOREIGN KEY (lend_to) REFERENCES people(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (cd_id) REFERENCES cd(id),
  lend_date DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
  )
;

INSERT INTO people (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES 
(1, 'Brett', 'CEO'),
(2, 'Jeff', 'President'),
(3, 'Beta', 'Media'),
(4, 'Casey', 'Content')
;

INSERT INTO cd (id, artist, title, owner) VALUES
(1, 'The xx', 'Coexist', 2),
(2, 'ACDC', 'High Voltage', 1),
(3, 'Bjork', 'Cocoon', 3),
(4, 'Ella Fitzgerald', 'Ella Sings Gershwin', 4),
(5, 'Fever Ray', 'Live in Lulea', 2),
(6, 'Tom Waits', 'Rain Dogs', 4),
(7, 'Howlin Wolf', 'Smokestack Lightning', 1),
(8, 'Tupac', 'Poetic Justice', 4)

;


INSERT INTO lend (id, cd_id, lend_to, lend_date) VALUES
(1, 2, 3, '2014/01/03'),
(2, 3, 1, '2014/04/02'),
(3, 7, 4, '2013/12/22'),
(4, 4, 2, '2014/01/03')

;
```

I want my query to show who the CD is lent to. I can get the ID from the lend table, but want to display the full name of the individual lending it from the people table. Do I need to rework the design of how the lend table connects to the people table, or just use some sort of case function in the query? Below is my query so-far where I'm getting the l.lent_to and want to be showing the CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name) who the CD is lent to.

```
SELECT /*cd.id,*/ 
      CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name) 'CD OWNER',
         cd.title,

    l.lend_to,
    p.id ,

      (
        CASE 
            WHEN l.lend_to IS NULL
            THEN 'Not Lent'
            ELSE DATE_FORMAT(l.lend_date, '%m-%d-%Y')
        END
      ) 'LEND DATE',

      (
        CASE
          WHEN l.lend_to IS NULL
          THEN 'Not Lent'
          ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, l.lend_date, NOW())
        END
       ) 'DAYS LENT'


FROM 
people p
LEFT JOIN cd cd
ON p.id = cd.owner

LEFT JOIN lend l
ON cd.id = l.cd_id

LEFT JOIN lend l1
on p.id = l1.lend_to

;
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this query gives you the basic information you are looking for

```
select c.title as 'Title', c.artist as 'Artist', o.first_name as 'Owner', 
l.lend_date as 'Lend Date', p.first_name as 'Lender'
 from cd c
left outer join people o on c.owner = o.id
left outer join lend l on c.id = l.cd_id
left outer join people p on l.lend_to = p.id
```

You can add additional switch logic to refine the result, if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, ArunGeorge. I'm afraid, however that this doesn't solve the problem of showing the names of the lender and lendee on the same line of the query result. I'm beginning to see the problem as an architecture flaw. Any query would need to join the people table on the p.id. the lendee could never be returned. Now I'm trying to see how I might redesign the schema to allow both the lender and lendee to be returned while still adhering to sound RDBMS principles and avoiding duplication of data in multiple tables, i.e. the names of lenders and lendees.

Comment: Is the Owner on the cd the person who is lending it? If yes, doesn't the above query give the owner detail of each cd, along with the details of the person to whom it is give on lend? Just trying to figure out what is the missing piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue with a data architecture redesign. Take a look if interested.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6158/3